# Golang SDK for Dynamodb : ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure does not return the details about conditions when conditionchcekfailure occurs

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

I am using golang sdk https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.45.26/ to debug conditional check errors and find information about why the failure occured in sIngle write operations, but I can only see the error Message_: "The conditional request failed". No other information regarding specific reason is provided when using the parameter ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure: ALL_OLD in UpdateItemInput. In case of TransactWriteItems I can see specific reason of conditional check failure when using the same parameter. How can I obtain those details for single write operations as well? Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/06/amazon-dynamodb-cost-failed-conditional-writes The syntax I am using:

```
input := &dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
        TableName:                           aws.String("DummyTable"),
        Key:                                 keyAttr,
        ExpressionAttributeValues:           updateExpr.Values(),
        ExpressionAttributeNames:            updateExpr.Names(),
        ConditionExpression:                 updateExpr.Condition(),
        ReturnValues:                        aws.String(dynamodb.ReturnValueAllOld),
        UpdateExpression:                    updateExpr.Update(),
        ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure: aws.String(dynamodb.ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailureAllOld),
}
output, err := dl.ddbI.UpdateItem(input)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item should be within the error component usually in `error.response.Item`.

For example in python:

```
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:
    if error.response["Error"]["Code"] == "ConditionalCheckFailedException":
        print("The conditional expression is not met")
        current_value = error.response.get("Item")
```

*Note: if you're using DynamoDB Local this feature does not yet exist*

Comment: Hi, I have tried printing the completing error but it only has the field "Metadata" and "Message" in case of single write operation. In case of Transactions there is an additional field "CancellationReasons"  which contains the item. However I am trying to get the same thing for UpdateItem() and its not returning the old item value.
Thanks

Comment: Are you certain the item you are updating already exists?

Comment: I am certain that the item I am trying to update exists. I verified it is getting successfully updated when all conditions are getting satisfied. Here's the complete error message in case of conditional check failure:
error="ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed\n{\n  RespMetadata: {\n    StatusCode: 400,\n    RequestID: \"c99cb646-f17c-4a3c-8d5b-02813d57d830\"\n  },\n  Message_: \"The conditional request failed\"\n
Thanks

Comment: Any idea whether this feature can be used with dynamodb local or not ?

Comment: No, unfortunately it's not yet supported on Local

Comment: Okay then that is what was causing the issue, initially I was using dynamodb-local. Now tested on aws and it's working as expected, Thank you for updating the answer!

Answer (score 1):

As of Dec 18 2023, local dynamo supports it (versions 1.25.0 and 2.2.0 onwards): https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/12/amazon-dynamodb-local-two-api-features/

In go you could do something like this. Remember that the data won't come at *dynamodb.UpdateItemOutput, but at the error return var:

```
_, err = r.client.UpdateItem(context, updateItemInput)
if err != nil {
    var condErr *dynamotypes.ConditionalCheckFailedException
    if errors.As(err, &condErr) {
        if len(condErr.Item) > 0 {
          ...
        }
    }
}
```